# Script after system() works only when the application has been open beforehand

Tags: c++, automation, mouseevent

Hi so I wrote a automation script in c++ which clicks on things. `mouse_event`. The clicking happens only when the application was running already before the script starts.

The code likes this:

```
Int main()
{
Using namespace std;

string search;
cin >> search;

system(<Path to VMWARE>);
Sleep(2500);
SetCursorPos(250, 41);
...,
```

It opens VMWARE but the script stops. SetCursorPos() isn‘t executed.

When VMware is open when the script starts it works.

Any solutions for that? Thank you!

Comment: `system` is a *blocking* function, it will not return until the program you run exits.

Comment: Don't ever use `system`. It's a security nightmare. Use one of the `exec*` functions instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ohhh that explains a lot! Thank you

Comment: Considering your other code it seems you're running Windows. Then there are other alternatives, like for example [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa). Or possibly [`ShellExecute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude seriously I can't use them. Since I tred for many hour already I made a .bat that opens a shortcut to VMWARE. Very poor workaround I must admit.